# CSS3 Media Queries Not Working on Mobile

Tags: css, media-queries, css-position

I am trying to write a media query for the iphone 6 display, but I can't figure out why none of the changes are taking effect in the chrome dev tools view. The other pages on my site didn't have this issue. Here are the current media queries and the elements I am trying to modify with them.

```
body {
  background-image: url("../images/home.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left; 
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 570px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
  font-family: "Yellowtailregular";
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 8px gray;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1700ms;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1700ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
}


@media only screen and (max-width : 2048px) {
  body {
    background-position: center;
  }
  #navbar {
    width: 93.9%;
    position: relative;
    left: 63px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1922px) {
 body {
  background-position: center left;
 }
 #navbar {
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
 }

}
```

Here is the media query I am trying to make. Is the former query causing the issue or does it have to do with my bootstrap columns?

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  body {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

I know this isn't a lot to go on, so I will add additional information as requested.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Please check your view port tag should be <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @raj This solved my question. Add it as a solution and ill mark it :)